# How to fill an array from some position

Tags: php

for example I have an array :

```
$array = array(25, 50, 75, 100); // I get an array of some numbers
$position = 50; // I get some value to start with
$limit = 3; // I need to fill another array with 3 next values from the starting position
```

and now what code I need to use to fill a new array just like this:

```
$new_array = array(75, 100, 25); // the start position is 50, but I need the next 3
```

any ideas??

Comment: after the position of 50 there is no 3 elements in the array, there are only two, 75 and 100. so can you clarify a question bit more?

Comment: yes, i need those 2 next AND THEN restart from the first element how to do that trick?

Comment: I think he is taking first element of array after reaching to end

Comment: if while filling the array it reaches the end of it, it goes to the beginning and while the limit is more than the length of the filled array...i need some advice

Comment: it depends upon your requirement. for what purpose are you making this script?

Comment: i get an array of articles id, then i need to get all the next IDS from the current id article

Comment: so if I am in the article id = 8, and the list of articles id is = array(1, 4, 7, 8, 9) - then i need to fill it with, 9, 1, 4, 7 - except 8  -because is the current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like having functions to abstract the logic. So I would suggest to write a function which takes the array, the position to start with and the limit:

```
<?php
function loop_array($array,$position,$limit) {

    //find the starting position...
    $key_to_start_with = array_search($position, $array);
    $results = array();

    //if you couldn't find the position in the array - return null
    if ($key_to_start_with === false) {
        return null;
    } else {
            //else set the index to the found key and start looping the array
        $index = $key_to_start_with;
        for($i = 0; $i<$limit; $i++) {
                    //if you're at the end, start from the beginning again
            if(!isset($array[$index])) {
                $index = 0;
            }
            $results[] = $array[$index];
            $index++;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

So now you can call the function with any value you want, e.g.:

```
$array = array(25, 50, 75, 100);
$position = 75;
$limit = 3;

$results = loop_array($array,$position,$limit);

if($results != null) {
    print_r($results);
} else {
    echo "The array doesn't contain '{$position}'";
}
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 75
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 25
)
```

Or you could loop it with any other values:

```
$results = loop_array(array(1,2,3,4,5), 4, 5);
```

Here's a working example: http://codepad.org/lji1D84J

Comment: would have never guessed, fantastic))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the position of the keyword inside your array. [% arithmetic operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for going to first element after reaching end. Rest is your logic.

```
<?php
    $array = array(25, 50, 75, 100);
    $position = 10;
    $limit = sizeof($array)-1;

    $pos = array_search($position, $array);;

    if(!($pos === false))
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
        {
            $pos = (($pos+1)%sizeof($array));
            echo $array[$pos]."<br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not Found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: i don't know why but the array_search returns me 0, because it finds it at the first position, but then 0 - is like false

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to achieve your goal.

let's say you know the position of 50 is at 2.

then you can get a new array by -

```
array_slice(array_merge(array_slice($array, 2), array_slice($array, 0, 2)), 3);
```

Basically, you get two sub-array from the start position, concatenate together, and then remove the tailing part.